# Disable oh-my-zsh tab completion for first command parameter, when it's a directory

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've recently switched to Zsh+Oh my Zsh, and I found a very annoying behavior.

When in my path I have a directory and an executable sharing the same prefix, tab completion includes the directory even when it's the first [0] parameter in the commandline, which is not useful, since it's not executable anyway.

Suppose I have in my path:

```
library      # directory
library.rb   # executable
```

when I type `lib` as first parameter in the commandline:

```
$ lib<tab>
```

tab completion will complete to `library`.

Can I prevent (Oh My) Zsh to try include directories in this case?

Comment: If the option `auto_cd` is turned on (I don't know if oh-my-zsh does this by default), the directory *is* executable: running `library` is equivalent to `cd library`. Zsh should offer `library` as an option only if `auto_cd` is on. Do you want to turn off `auto_cd`, do you want to make completion inconsistent with what you can actually run, or is the problem that `auto_cd` is off but completions are inconsistent and offer the directory anyway?

Comment: I'm puzzled, because on my system, the auto cd (if this is the functionality) fails. With the example above, the result of executing `library` would be `zsh: permission denied: scrape_movies`. even more puzzling, if I actually manually `cd` into that dir, it gets subsequently excluded from the autocompletion.